# Maven : Modifying the manifest files of dependency JARs

Tags: maven, jar, dependency-injection

any help or pointers would really be much appreciated.
I need to inject two fields into the Manifest file of all the dependency JARs of my project on build-time.

The dependency jars is already build and gets pulled from a repo.
I need to find a way to get the Manifest file of the JAR and then modify it with the variables in my current pom file.
Has anyone done this before of know how to do this.
Thanks in advance for your time and reply

Comment: Why would you like to do that, cause those artifacts are already built which means in other words immutable. You can change those artifacts via a combination of maven-dependency-plugin and maven-assembly-plugin but it would produce a really large pom file. On the other you are changing already built artifacts which will be against the idea of Maven.

Comment: The `maven-assembly-plugin` allows you to specify the manifest config, however there is currently a [bug](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MASSEMBLY-450) which prevents one from merging an existing manifest with additional manifest entries.  I found this because I attempted to do the same thing and failed.

Comment: It may be a possibility to create an uber-jar from your dependencies using the shade plugin: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/ and modify the Manifest the way you need it

Comment: Can you give some more details on what you want to accomplish? Why do you need to modify the manifest? What are the variables that you want to replace?

Comment: @kazanaki Would be great to use for adding `Automatic-Module-Names:` to the manifest now when we have a probability of jar name collision in java9

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really something that Maven allows you to do. From Maven's perspective, every JAR with a specific name should be exactly the same as every other JAR with the same name.

For example, let's say my project depends on `abc-1.0.jar`. I specify this dependency because the ALphabet team published an `abc` library with a specified API for the 1.0 version. I ought to be able to get this jar file from any repository in the world, even from my neighbor down the street when my Internet goes out and manually install it to my local repository, and it should be exactly the same file. If it weren't the same file, then I wouldn't have the guarantee that the `.class` files inside the jar would contain the library code I need to make my build succeed without errors.

If you're *really* motivated to make this work, well, it's theoretically possible. You can write a script that will:

1. Parse the POM XML for the `properties` section and parse out the individual properties from there as well as the names of the dependency jars
2. For every dependency jar with a classifier "manifest_injected", try to find it in the local repository. If it does not exist, generate an empty Maven project with the given dependencies (without the `manifest_injected` classifier), run `mvn validate` on it to make sure that the dependencies have been downloaded and placed in the local repository if they have been found
3. Clone all said JAR files, open the clones, do the manifest injection that you need with the properties you parsed earlier, and save the injected jars into the proper places in the Maven repository
4. Call the Maven build that was passed to the script as an argument.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily in your binary repository. For example, Artifactory allows you to write [a user plugin that will be triggered on any download](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/User+Plugins#UserPlugins-Download). In this listener you can write your own code - open up the jar, change the manifest and serve the changed jar instead of the original (and cache it for next time).